# app crash while retrieving chat message list from firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am developing live chat app through firebase realtime database so message sent successfully but after that i am trying to get messages list at that time i am getting crash

Here is i have tried some code which i want to show you please have a look on my code

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
```

**inside viewDidLoad()**

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

func loadMessageData() {
    self.ref.child("Message").observe(.childAdded, andPreviousSiblingKeyWith: { (snapshot, str) in
        print(snapshot)
        if let dictonary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            print(snapshot)
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

I am adding screen shot Here of my message table structure so please have a look

**Error Message**

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
>
> 2019-06-25 09:50:52.088617+0530 SMSApp[4378:1003736] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: put break point her : self.ref.child("Message") and check it in console i think it will return nil

Comment: remove  print(snapshot) outside if block

Comment: can you put more code like where is self.ref is initialize

Comment: @JaydeepVyas please check i have updated code

Comment: make sure self.ref.child("Message") this will not return nil

Comment: I am not sure your code is doing what you expect, and the use of andPreviousSiblingKeyWith is unclear in this use case. You're adding an observer to the Message node which will iterate over each child node, one at a time and read in all of the data within that child. So in this case, it will read in the XXzJ node and all of it's data, which will be the value. Then it will read khrV node and all of its data. Is that the intention? Can you share which line is crashing?

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as **text**, not links and images. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: @pkamb no, that link will not help as they are not force unwrapping any optionals. For any future readers; that code will not crash with that dataset. Not going to happen so the issue lies outside of that code but the question was never updated as to where.